# I can't install Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 10 these errors appear while installation

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, failed-installation

When I tried to install VS 2010 on Windows 10, the installation ends with errors as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

I tried to download another copy of VS 2010 but the same errors appeared.

I stopped the antivirus and check the latest update but the same errors appeared.

Comment: Why do you want to install such an old, long-gone version of VS ?? And did you look at the detailed errors in the log file - as the error dialog suggests? What do you see in those logs?

Comment: because i cant create report in vs 2017 and this is another problem